# Trying to implement Import DropDown on Swift, I get a pod installation error

Tags: swift

Trying to Install pod in Swift with this procedure,:
[image: PodInstallProcedure]

I get this error in step number 7 (pod install):

[image: The Error]

Can you tell me how to solve this?

Now my project can't build successfully:

[image]

Podfile
[image: My Podfile]

After opening my project in terminal with vim and deleting all lines that contains "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES" and run the command "pod install" again, I get only this error:
[image: The error]

The Build error:
[image: The build error]

Comment: There are no errors in the screenshots you posted. And you did not post what error Xcode gives when you try to build

Comment: Did you really open the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj ?

Comment: Now, I include the Xcode error that gives when I try to build.

Comment: I'm asking again, because I don't think you opened it: `Did you really open the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj ?` If you opened the xcworkspace, you should see, at the same level of "Sales Tax 2", with the blue icon, "Pods", in the left panel of Xcode (Project Navigator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is open the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj.  Thanks